# What group does the user running a command with elevated permissions belong to?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, permissions, cmd.exe

I am not particularly familiar with Windows permissions, but I had assumed that elevated permissions were equivalent to sudo. However, I came across this "unexpected" behavior when running a simple python program via cmd.exe and powershell, which leads me to believe that it's not so clear-cut:

When the target directory has 755 permissions (the default), I cannot write to the directory if I'm running cmd.exe/powershell with elevated permissions. I can write to the directory if I'm not running elevated. If I change the directory permissions to 766, I can write to it with either elevated/regular permissions.

Using windows cli (cmd.exe or powershell):

```
echo "asdf" > testdir\testfile.txt
```

And a minimal example in python:

```python
import os 

def main():
    fname = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "testdir", "testfile.txt")
    f = open(fname, "w")
    f.write("asdf")
    f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So, what group does the elevated user belong to? And why does the elevated user not have permissions to directories that they created as a "non-elevated" user?

Comment: It depends, an elevation of permissions, typically means the Administrator group.  However, it’s normal to have several different user groups, which all have higher permissions then a user in the User group.  You will ha e to provide more information for any answer to be submitted

Comment: @Ramhound - do you know of any way to find out what all the groups/group permissions are? All I know is that the elevated group is not equivalent to the admin group

Comment: @asdf- If you running the process with “run as administrator” it certainly is a member of that group.  How do you know the elevated group isn’t part of the Administrators user group?

Comment: @Ramhound - I'm using the "Run Elevated" option (appears when you right-click). This is on my company machine and SW devs have "elevated" but not Administrator permissions (I can click the "run as admin option", but my credentials don't work)

Comment: You will have to ask your Administrator what user group the elevated user is in exactly.  “Run Elevated” isn’t a default right-click menu item and is custom to your work environment.  **It was added by your Administrator**. You will have to answer this question yourself since the name of the user group isn’t know to us

Comment: `whoami`, `gpresult /v`, and `icacls "c:\folder"`.  I have no idea what is 755 is. Obviously not a Windows thing.

Comment: Administrators have two security tokens. One unelevated with same permissions as a User and an elevated one.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the suggestions; I'll ask the admin team

Comment: @Mark I was referring to folder permissions. I'm not sure what the windows terminology is, but each number indicates which bits are set for owner, group, and all users (so 755 = 111 101 101 = rwxr-xr-x = owner can read/write/execute, but all others can only read/execute)